# What happened to ng-title directive in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I had this code in Angular 1:

```html
<div ng-title="item.favourite ? 'Remove' : 'Add'">
  <i class="someClass"> </i>
</div>
```

Angular 2 doesn't have a `[ngTitle]` and I didn't find anything related in the docs.

Should I use `title="{{item.favourite ? 'Remove' : 'Add'}}"` or is there an "Angular 2 way"?

Comment: I don't see an ng-title in AngularJS. Where did you get that from?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You could use:

```
<div [attr.title]="item.favourite ? 'Remove' : 'Add'">
```

That will bind to the `title` attribute to your expression.

Comment: I just want to interpret \n but the above doesn't work for me at all webpage can't be loaded because of maflormed html.